# how to decode the following string

Tags: python, lxml, decode

I was trying to decode the following string and getting a error.

```
item = lh.fromstring(items[1].text).text_content().strip().decode('utf-8')

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20a8' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any idea whats wrong?

```
items[1].text = <strong>₨ 18,500 </strong> 
repr(items[1].text) = u'\u20a8 18,500'
```

Comment: Please post the value of `items[1].text` so we can help you.

Comment: Relevant http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20a8/index.htm

Comment: `repr(items[1].text)` would probably be more useful. (and edit your question rather than providing the information in comments)

Comment: Umm, I meant show *us* `repr(items[1].text)`, not to use that in your code. It won't throw that error but it will be very ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you've called `decode` but your error is citing `encode` is a clue that your string is Unicode to start with, not a bytestring. `decode` is for converting from bytestrings to Unicode, `encode` is for the other way round.

Comment: python3 makes this more clear, there you have `bytes` with the method decode, and `str` with the method encode.

Comment: sorry guys i was looking it  totally in the opposite way

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to decode an already decoded (Unicode) string. So, drop `.decode('utf-8')` and it should work. Unless, you mean something else by 'decode' (maybe you want to *encode* the string to some specific encoding).